# Unable to deepcopy a class with both __init__ and __new__ defined

Tags: python, copy, new-operator, python-internals

I'm having (what seems to me) a slightly weird problem. I have defined a class with both **init** and **new** defined, below:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, num1):
        self.num1 = num1

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_inst = object.__new__(cls)
        new_inst.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        new_inst.extra = 2
        return new_inst
```

If put to normal use, this works fine:

```
test = Test(1)
assert test.extra == 2
```

However, it will not copy.deepcopy:

```
import copy
copy.deepcopy(test)
```

gives

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num1'
```

This may be related to [Decorating class with class wrapper and __new__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956677/decorating-class-with-class-wrapper-and-new) - I can't see exactly how but I'm trying a similar thing here - I need **new** to apply a class wrapper to the Test instance I've created.

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically it's not an issue to call `__init__` from `__new__`, but it's redundant as a call to `__init__`  happens automatically once `__new__` returns the instance.

---

#### Now coming to why `deepcopy` fails, we can look into [its internals](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/copy.py#L128) a bit.

When `__deepcopy__` isn't defined on the class it falls to this condition:

```
reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce_ex__", None)
rv = reductor(4)
```

Now, here `reductor(4)` returns the [function to be used to re-create the object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/copyreg.py#L90), the type of the object(`Test`), arguments to be passed and its state(in this case the items in instance dictionary `test.__dict__`):

```
>>> !rv
(
    <function __newobj__ at 0x7f491938f1e0>,  # func
    (<class '__main__.Test'>,),  # type + args in a single tuple
    {'num1': 1, 'extra': []}, None, None) # state
```

Now it calls [`_reconstruct`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/copy.py#L258) with this data:

```
def _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args,
                 state=None, listiter=None, dictiter=None,
                 deepcopy=deepcopy):
    deep = memo is not None
    if deep and args:
        args = (deepcopy(arg, memo) for arg in args)
    y = func(*args)
    ...
```

Here this call will end up calling:

```
def __newobj__(cls, *args):
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
```

But since `args` is empty and cls being `<class '__main__.Test'>`, you get the error.

---

#### Now how does Python decides these arguments for your object, as that seem to be the problem?

For that we need to look into: `reductor(4)`, where reductor is `__reduce_ex__` and the `4` passed here is pickle protocol version.

Now this `__reduce_ex__` internally calls [`reduce_newobj`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L4487) to get the object creation function, arguments, state etc for the new copy to be made.

The arguments in itself are found out using [`_PyObject_GetNewArguments`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L4346).

Now this function looks for `__getnewargs_ex__` or `__getnewargs__` on the class, since our class doesn't have it, we get nothing for arguments.

---

Now let's add this method and try again:

```
import copy


class Test:

    def __init__(self, num1):
        self.num1 = num1

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return ('Eggs',)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        new_inst = object.__new__(cls)
        new_inst.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        new_inst.extra = []
        return new_inst

test = Test([])

xx = copy.deepcopy(test)

print(xx.num1, test.num1, id(xx.num1), id(test.num1))

# ([],)
# ('Eggs',)
# [] [] 139725263987016 139725265534088
```

Surprisingly the deepcopy `xx` doesn't have `Eggs` stored in `num1` even though we're returning it from `__getnewargs__`. This is because the function `_reconstruct` re-adds a deepcopy of the state it obtained originally to the instance after its creation, hence overriding these changes.

```
def _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args,
                 state=None, listiter=None, dictiter=None,
                 deepcopy=deepcopy):
    deep = memo is not None
    if deep and args:
        args = (deepcopy(arg, memo) for arg in args)
    y = func(*args)
    if deep:
        memo[id(x)] = y

    if state is not None:
        ...
            if state is not None:
                y.__dict__.update(state)  <---
    ...
```

---

#### Are there any other ways to do it?

Note the above explanation and the working function is just for explaining the issue. I wouldn't really call it the best or worse way to do it.

Yes, you could define you own [`__deepcopy__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) hook on the class to control the behavior further. I'd leave this an exercise to the user.

Comment: thank you - this has improved my understanding. So, if a class has both a __new__ and __init__ method, the problem occurs because _PyObject_GetNewArguments checks the __new__ for arguments, and not the __init__? Out of curiosity, would a more sensible behaviour for deepcopy to be to check both __init__ and __new__ args, and aggregate them?

Comment: No, `_PyObject_GetNewArguments` isn't looking into `__init__` and `__new__` at all to figure out the arguments, as mentioned [it checks whether you've defined `__getnewargs_ex__` or `__getnewargs__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L4432).

Comment: It is possible check the signature of `__new__` or `__init__`,  there's even a [builtin lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) for that. But the real problem is finding out what values to pass for the arguments, since for that it need to find out where and how `Test` was called, which unfortunately in Python is very hard to determine.

Comment: Sure - so it might be said that the root of the problem is that deepcopy is unable to retroactively determine how the arguments had been assigned between new and init - and therefore is unable to correctly reconstruct the original object.

Comment: @Chrisper In other words, it doesn't know how to instantiate `Test` unless you tell it explicitly how to.

Answer (score 0):

OK - it's because I'm doing it wrong - I shouldn't explicitly call **init** from **new**. Culpe mea.